# Living and Working in different states than resident states

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, primary-residence

My husband and I are in a quandary. We were TX residents with drivers licenses and vehicles registered in that state (but no real property). We purchased a 5th Wheel that we live in full time. We traveled from state to state for my husband's job. He is in construction.

In 2013, he got a long term job in SC. Previous jobs were 2-6 months, then we would move.

In Dec of 2014 we purchased a cabin in GA. We travel there for weekends and this will be where we retire in a few years.

Then in Feb 2015, I began working part time in SC. We never changed our drivers licenses or vehicle registrations to SC. We live in an RV Park.

In Sept 2015, my husband's job transferred him to a jobsite in PA. The location is very close to the DE border and my husband ended up getting an apartment in DE as it was only 3 miles to the jobsite from there. I did not move to DE with him because of my job, so I am still in SC living in the 5th wheel.

Quite a mix, don't you agree?

I understand that we will need to get new drivers and register our vehicles. My questions is where? What is our primary residence?

Should I get a drivers license in SC and register my car and rv in SC?
Should my husband do the same for himself in DE?
Or should we both do it in GA as there is where our home is?

I'm also not sure what address we should use for filing income tax. We have previously used our TX address. Should we file separately, me in SC and him in DE?

Do you think you can help me figure this all out? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I heard some common sense criteria once for determining where your residence actually is:

Wherever the toothbrush you actually use is sitting, that is your current residence.

But maybe you should consult a lawyer regarding this question. It appears complex enough to justify a specialist.

Comment: Well, we had a judge here rule that your home is where your cat is.  (The question was whether a politician lived in his district or not.)

Comment: I dunno about anyone else, but I take my toothbrush with me when traveling (and I used tgo occasionally take the cat too.). Everything should be as simple as possible.... But not simpler. And law, unfortunately, often has little to do with common sense